# Computer's folder on network empty, after I login into it

Tags: network-shares, windows-explorer

I am trying to access another computer's files on my network, but I am having a problem. When I go to Windows Explorer --> then click on Network --> then click on another computer on my network --> then enter the login details, it is accepted but there is nothing in the window. The Users and some other shared folders are suppose to appear, but don't.

Here is a screenshot of the blank windows [image: http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/2893/yddo.png]

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure there are files in `shared folder` on the computer you are about to access?
2. Are you sure both machines are in the same `work group`?

And a proper place to ask this question is [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) stack. You can access it using you StackExchange account and repost your question there. I would recommend providing more information on how you configured your home network.

### edit

As MadHatter said in the comment below, please don't post the question again. Instead, flag this for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved.

Comment: Synthesis, if you decide to follow this advice, **please don't post the question again**.  Instead, flag this for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved.